# Smoke and fire not showing up in my eevee render

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, eevee-render-engine, fire

In my render the fire with smoke physics are not rendering for some reason, I've been breaking my head about this. I use blender 2.8 and the Eevee renderer.
I'll have a download link to my file.
Somebody please help!

Comment: https://transfernow.net/857n13j58q64 the link for the blender file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue until I realized that I typed in 'Density' instead of 'density' in the attribute node.

This should work:

[image: Smoke Node tree]

Answer (score 0):

Enabled "Volumetric" Under the Render tab ? - Had the same problem and that did the trick :)